# One View Controller Portrait, The Other Landscape

Tags: iphone, ipad, rotation, xcode4.5, uiinterfaceorientation

I have the initial view controller that is portrait, and I want the next view controller to only be landscape. The user can't turn the iPhone/iPad to change rotation. Can someone please help me with this?

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is : [shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) method of `UIViewController` Class.

This function returns `YES` if the orientations is supported by your `UIView`. If you `return YES` only to the `landscape orientation`, then the iPhone will automatically be put in that orientation.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscape);
}
```

GoodLuck !!!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for [`UIViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation%3a) or some of the other orientation related members.